# Dynamic dags not getting added by scheduler

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to create Dynamic DAGs and then get them to the scheduler. I tried the reference from https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/ which works well. I changed it a bit as in the below code. Need help in debugging the issue.

I tried
1. Test run the file. The Dag gets executed and the globals() is printing all the DAGs objects. But somehow not listing in the list_dags or in the UI

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
import json
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator

def create_dag(dag_id,
               dag_number,
               default_args):

    def hello_world_py(*args):
        print('Hello World')
        print('This is DAG: {}'.format(str(dag_number)))

    dag = DAG(dag_id,
              schedule_interval="@hourly",
              default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='hello_world',
            python_callable=hello_world_py,
            dag_number=dag_number)

    return dag


def fetch_new_dags(**kwargs):

    for n in range(1, 10):
        print("=====================START=========\n")
        dag_id = "abcd_" + str(n) 
        print (dag_id)
        print("\n")
        globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id, n, default_args)
        print(globals())

default_args = {
    'owner': 'diablo_admin',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 8, 8),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'trigger_rule': 'none_skipped'
    #'schedule_interval': '0 * * * *'
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('testDynDags', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *')
#schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *'

check_for_dags = PythonOperator(dag=dag,
                   task_id='tst_dyn_dag',
                   provide_context=True,
                   python_callable=fetch_new_dags
                   )




check_for_dags
```

Expected to create 10 DAGs dynamically and added to the scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess doing the following would fix it

- completely remove the global `testDynDags` dag and `tst_dyn_dags` task (instantiation and invocation)
- invoke your `fetch_new_dags(..)` method with requisite arguments in global scope

---

Explanation

- Dynamic dags / tasks merely means that you **have a well-defined logic at the time of writing dag-definition file** that can help create tasks / dags having a known structure in a pre-defined fashion.
- **You can NOT determine the structure of your DAG at runtime** (task execution). So, for instance, you cannot add n identical tasks to your DAG if the upstream task returned an integer value n. But you can iterate over a YAML file containing n segments and generate n tasks / dags.

So clearly, wrapping dag-generation code inside an Airflow task itself makes no sense.

---

**UPDATE-1**

From what is indicated in comments, I infer that the requirement dictates that you revise your external source that feeds inputs (how many dags or tasks to create) to your DAG / task-generation script. While this is indeed a complex use-case, but a simple way to achieve this is to create 2 separate DAGs.

- One dag runs once in a while and generates the inputs that are stored in an an external resource like Airflow Variable (or any other external store like file / S3 / database etc.)
- The second DAG is constructed programmatically by reading that same datasource which was written by the first DAG

You can take inspiration from the [`Adding DAGs based on Variable value` section](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/)

Comment: Thank you Shubham. My intention is to create new dags with same structure and the inputs for the tasks in each DAG varies including the schedule. Hence, the logic and I need the testDynDags to be running at regular frequency. If I remove testDynDags and tst_dyn_dags task. How can I keep invoking the fetch_new_dags method from external sources (since I could not find an API to perform)?
Currently, in the tst_dyn_dags task, I am actually calling a rest api and checking for new dag_ids that are to be created along with required arguments.

Comment: Thank you again Shubham. I achieved this using One DAG (which invokes the python program) and one python program that just creates DAGs .

Comment: @Saideep can you guide me on how you achieve this?